# Error 1004 when using data validation drop-down list

Tags: excel, validation, drop-down-menu, vba

I have problem when I use the validation data drop-down list.
I’ve registered the macro that should show drop-down list if a conditio is met (drop down list is based on a named range). When i type this manually and add data validation to the selected range, it works fine, but when I try to use macro, it fails and show the Error 1004 at line .Add. It is also imposible to register macro and run it after.
Here is the code:

```
Dim kolQ as Range
Set kolQ = (here is range in column Q)
With kolQ.Validation
.Delete
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=IF(AND($L2<DATE(2014;5;1);$M2>DATE(2015;4;30));list_a;list_b)"
.IgnoreBlank = True
.InCellDropdown = True
.InputTitle = ""
.ErrorTitle = "No valid status!"
.InputMessage = ""
.ErrorMessage = "Chose option from drop-down list!"
.ShowInput = True
.ShowError = True
End With
```

I’ve searched trough the forum and google about that, but all the answers I’ve found don’t work in this case.
The named ranges (list_a, list_b) exists in another sheet of workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing formula like this, local region formatting gets ignored, so semi-colons that work fine in a cell will fail. You'll need to alter your formula from:

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=IF(AND($L2<DATE(2014;5;1);$M2>DATE(2015;4;30));list_a;list_b)"
```

To:

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=IF(AND($L2<DATE(2014,5,1),$M2>DATE(2015,4,30)),list_a,list_b)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `;` to `,` in your `Formula1`.
Also, try incorporating `CHOOSE` function. Something like:

```
Formula1:="=CHOOSE(IF(AND($L2<DATE(2014,5,1),$M2>DATE(2015,4,30)),1,2),list_a,list_b)"
```

Comment: ";" results probably from Polish system settings. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

use Range.Activate and  With ActiveCell.Validation
like suggested here on #3

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/adding-data-validation-via-vba-returns-1004-error.331279/

it just helped me

Comment: Can you update your answer to provide further explanation of the solution, instead of relying primarily on the link? Answers should stand on their own even if the link is later removed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your validation list is only one column wide.  I was getting 1004 error when trying to use an existing named range until I realised the existing named range was two columns wide.  Had to create a new named range that was only one column wide which fixed the problem.